# erlide, which eclipse/which packages?

Tags: erlang, erlide

I have downloaded eclipse 3.4 (java version) for MacOSX (carbon).  I have tried to 'update' to the erlide, but see many (duplicated) options (many erlide, options that say 'only for erl SDK updates', etc.)  Sometimes I get 403 errors when attempting to access http://erlide.org/update and http://erlide.sourceforge.net/update.

Finally, when I get some set of options installed, I either get errors like :

```
Loading of /Users/kevindtimm/Documents/eclipse-java-ganymede-SR2-macosx-carbon/eclipse/plugins/org.erlide.kernel.common_0.8.1.201005250801/ebin/erlide_kernel_common.beam failed: badfile
(hello_world@ktmac)1> 
=ERROR REPORT==== 24-Nov-2010::19:17:32 ===
beam/beam_load.c(1768): Error loading function erlide_kernel_common:monitor/0: op put_string u u x:
  please re-compile this module with an R14B compiler
```

or, when I've done different installations of erlide, I get no response in the console to :

```
hello:hello().
```

Does anybody have a good reference for how to load this plug-in and which items I should install?

```
-module(hello).
-export([hello/0]).
hello() -> io:write("Hello World\n").
```

[edit]

I have installed eclipse 3.6 (c++) as requested below, and the following code still can't find hello:hello().

```
%%file_comment
-module(hello).

%%
%% Include files
%%

%%
%% Exported Functions
%%
-export([hello/0]).

%%
%% API Functions
%%



%%
%% Local Functions
%%
hello() -> io:write("Hello World\n").
```

[/edit]

Comment: Which version of Erlang do you have installed?

Comment: It looks to me like you have something compiled with an earlier version of Erlang that doesn't seem to play nice with the version you have installed.

Comment: @OJ - does OSX come with any other erlang?  I ask because I've only installed erlang once.

Comment: It is probably such that you get a compiled .beam file (akin to a java .class file) from R13B while your system is R14B. Look for where erlide_kernel_common.beam is on your system. If it is part of the erlide package, then I guess that is the problem.

Comment: I installed on ubuntu 10.04 (which has erl R13B?).  I now receive nothing when I type hello:hello(). into the console.  No response at all.  any information about which parts of the plug-in I'm supposed to install?  (I only ticked the first box, everything else looked unnecessary)  See my hello.erl module in the original question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It might be a little late for you, but maybe for others my set up might avoid some frustrations.

I have OSX 10.6.5, 64-bit and Erlang R14B installed.

After several false starts, I found the following worked:

- Download the **C++ version** of Eclipse (I use the latest Helios, 64-bit, OSX)
- Once extracted, start Eclipse
- Open Help | Eclipse Marketplace (wait whilst it fetches data)
- Type erlide into the search field and click Go
- Proceed to install by following the instructions
- Restart Eclipse after installing plugins (always a good idea)

Next, define an Erlang runtime, because this is not picked up automatically:

- Open Eclipse preferences
- Expand the Erlang entry shown on the left-hand side (do not select Erlang)
- In the expanded list click on the Installed Runtimes entry
- Define your runtime as appropriate
- Restart Eclipse

Failure to do the above steps first, (i.e. opening a different Erlang preferences pane) causes an internal UI error inside Eclipse, that prevents you from closing the dialog. Thus, forcing you to kill Eclipse.

Finally, it is necessary to define a launch configuration before you can run your Erlang code inside Eclipse:

- Open Run | Run Configurations
- Select Erlang application
- Add new launch configuration
- Enter a name for the application
- On the Erlang tab:
- Check required project
- On the Runtimes tab:
- Make sure node is defined as erlide
- Check "Start the Erlang node if not already running
- Click apply

Anyway, I hope it helps somebody out there.

Comment: I stopped because I wasn't able to complete this.  I will try later today and get back to you.  Thanks for the information.

Comment: This only seems to work with long name nodes, -sname nodes are not working properly.

Comment: It's much better now (maybe even fixed) but it doesn't seem to be able to run hello:hello().  from the source code posted above (see inside the edit)

Comment: So I edited the code down to just the module/export/hello() lines and it works like a charm.  Kudos to all!!!!!

Comment: Indigo (3.7) javascript version works fine too. https://github.com/erlide/erlide/wiki/Tutorial-Quick-Start